# Returning errors from AMFPHP on purpose

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, remoting, amfphp

When using flash remoting with amfphp, what can I write in php that will trigger the 'status' method that I set up in my Responder in Flash?

Or more generally, how can I determine if the service call has failed?  The ideal solution for me would be to throw some exception in php serverside, and catch that exception in flash clientside... How do other people handle server errors with flash remoting?

```
var responder = new Responder(
    function() {
        trace("some normal execution finished successfully.  this is fine.");
    }, function(e) { 
        trace("how do I make this trigger when my server tells me something bad happened?");
    } 
);
myService = new NetConnection;
myService.connect("http://localhost:88/amfphp/gateway.php");
myService.call("someclass.someservice", responder);
```

Comment: Sorry i cant follow you please clean your question, that  you can get fast help

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  Calling throw from php will trigger the Responder's error handler properly, but the tool I was using to sniff network traffic was getting in the way and messing up the calls.